# How to format resume for ATS, if can't use columns, text boxes or tables?

Tags: microsoft-word

Seems like most jobs now use ATS (applicant tracking system) to scan our resumes before a human ever sees them. So have to try to format my resume for an ATS.

[This article](https://premium.linkedin.com/jobsearch/articles/the-easy-how-to-guide-for-formatting-resumes-for-applicant-tracking-systems), and many like it, say the same thing: "Remove images, columns, tables, fields, text boxes and graphics so the ATS can quickly scan your text for keywords and phrases. The ATS may not be able to read data placed in images, tables, and text boxes, so it’s best to avoid them altogether."

They also say the resume has to be in Word format, to also have best chances of being read by the ATS.

So how would I get a Word document resume to look like the ones in the examples below?

(Without the skills dots, which are also not recommended).
I like this format because it looks more modern and clean, and provides more space to write. But, it's using tables and text boxes to do it.

If I use a normal Word document with no tables, columns or text boxes, it looks outdated, less professional, not as easy to read, and harder to get more info in one page.

This resume template from Google Docs also looks very clean and modern. But it uses tables too.

uptowork.com example:

[image]

Google Docs example:

[image]

Comment: 2 column layout?

Comment: "Avoid using multiple columns.  Some nice looking resume templates have information spread across two columns on a single page.  This is a sure fire way to confuse the ATS.  Keep it simple and stick to one column."
http://www.paddleyourownkanoo.com/2016/12/12/how-to-format-your-resume-to-be-ats-proof/

Comment: Well then you are stuffed :) the only ways I can think of to get your layout is either tables or columns. If you can't use either ...

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  That's also my conclusion after much research.  It's just not going to be a great looking resume, in order to comply with the ATS. And will likely be 2 pages now instead of 1.

Comment: Better to have a resume get read by the ATS, and possibly looked at by a real person, than have a great looking one that never gets seen (because the ATS can't read the data).

Comment: Another link with (seemingly) good info for passing the ATS:
https://www.pcc.edu/staff/pdf/1035/ApplicantTrackingSystem-Scanning.pdf

Comment: Another good point:
"However, if you’re applying for a job in a creative industry, providing a portfolio or examples of your past work can help your application stand out. For these types of positions, there will likely be a section to upload these materials separately, but you can always add a link to your personal blog or online portfolio in the “contact” section if you’re worried an ATS may screen these materials."
https://talentegg.ca/incubator/2016/07/20/build-atsfriendly-resume/

Comment: Nasty workaround comes to my mind... Create an eye candy multi-column resume - export to PDF and convert to a vector graphic image (without any text or metadata information in it). Then write resume with same information, but ATS optimized. Finally, put the vector image in the ATS optimized resume with higher Z-index than text. But it needs to be checked if an image above the text is ATS compatible.